# Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault when training images on mac

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to run a model to detect text. Before training it with my own dataset i tried to run it with training samples provided with it and followed all the instructions from https://github.com/argman/EAST.
I did not modify anything just ran it on my MacBook and i got following error when it tries to train images:

```
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-pack2 training images in /Users/shwaitkumar/Downloads/EAST-master/training_samples
ages/absl/app.py", line 250 in _run_main
  File Fatal Python error: "/opt/anSegmentation fault
```

It also gives me thes error:

```
2 training images in /Users/shwaitkumar/Downloads/EAST-master/training_samples
sing/popen_2 training images in /Users/shwaitkumar/Downloads/EAST-master/training_samples
fork.py", line 74 in _launch
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 20 in __init__
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py", line 277 in _Popen
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py", line 223 in _Popen
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 112 in start
  File "/Users/shwaitkumar/Downloads/EAST-master/data_util.py", line 81 in start
  File "/Users/shwaitkumar/Downloads/EAST-master/icdar.py", line 726 in get_batch
  File "multigpu_train.py", line 153 in main
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250 in _run_main
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299 in run
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40 in run
  File "multigpu_train.py", line 180 in <module>
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault
```

I searched online but couldn't find anything related to my case. Is it because I'm not using any gpu? Or the code requires to be run in python2 instead of python3? Can u please take a peek at the text detection model above to tell me why I'm getting this error and how to deal with it?